# Data from different tables have the same name, how to retrieve data?

Tags: php, sql, odbc

Here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT table1.Insert_ID, table1.Type, table1.Date "
    . "table2.User, table2.Date "
    . "FROM Insert AS table1 "
    . "INNER JOIN Contact AS table2 ON table2.Contact_ID = table1.Contact_ID";

$x =0;

while($row = odbc_fetch_array($res)){

$x++;

 $values= ($x . ": " . " Insert ID:". $row['Insert ID'] . " Date Created: " . $row['Date'] . " Date Modified:" . "\n");

print($values);


}
```

I want Date from both table1 and table2, how do I proceed to retrieve the data if they both have the same name?

Comment: same name doesn't mean much. the tables have to be related somehow (e.g. a foreign key relationship is possible), so you can use `JOIN` query. Otherwise you'll have to run two separate queries, or potentially one query with a `UNION`. But since you haven't provided any details about the structure, except "same name", we can't really help you.

Comment: you can use `AS` ie `table2.Date AS Date2`

Comment: How did I not provide enough information? Right now I'd want to use $row['Date'] but since two tables got the same name Date I can't specify which one I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an alias.

```
SELECT table1.Insert_ID, table1.Type, table1.Date as Date1 "
. "table2.User, table2.Date as Date2 "
. "FROM Insert AS table1 "
. "INNER JOIN Contact AS table2 ON table2.Contact_ID = table1.Contact_ID";
```

Answer (score 1):

Column aliases.

```
$sql = "SELECT table1.Insert_ID, table1.Type, table1.Date as T1Date "
    . "table2.User, table2.Date as T2Date"
    . "FROM Insert AS table1 "
    . "INNER JOIN Contact AS table2 ON table2.Contact_ID = table1.Contact_ID";
```